# "Special" meanders

Tags: lie-algebras, enumerative-combinatorics

One of the open problems in combinatorics is enumeration of *meanders*.

Here on MO I only could find them under the heading [not-especially-famous-long-open-problems-which-anyone-can-understand](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100265/not-especially-famous-long-open-problems-which-anyone-can-understand/103072#103072).

Since my interest is in some particular kind of these, I will not give the definition in the general case.

These special ones first appeared in a paper by Dergachev and Kirillov ["Index of Lie algebras of seaweed type"](https://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jlt/jlt10/DERGALAT2E.PDF).

Our meanders, unlike the general ones, can be described by pairs of compositions with equal sum. For example, 4+3+4=5+4+2 gives

[image: this is the good meander corresponding to 4+3+4=5+4+2]

Call this *good*: it consists of a single interval.

Here is another one, corresponding to 5+3+4=3+5+2+2:

[image: and this is the bad meander encoded by 5+3+4=3+5+2+2]

This is *bad* for two reasons: it is not connected, and it contains a non-interval (a cycle).

And here is a general (non-special) meander:

[image: this is not ours, it does not correspond to any pair of compositions]

One thus obtains a sequence of numbers $a(n)$, with the $n$th number equal to the number of pairs of compositions of $n$ which encode good special meanders.

There is a recurrence which was used by Martin Plechsmid to write a C program for calculating these numbers up to several dozens. This recurrence was first observed by D. I. Panyushev in ["Inductive formulas for the index of seaweed Lie algebras"](http://www.ams.org/distribution/mmj/vol1-2-2001/panyushev.pdf). In short, it is this: suppose given $a_1+a_2+...+a_k=b_1+b_2+...+b_l$ with $a_1>b_1$, let $d=a_1-b_1$ and let $r$ be the smallest nonnegative residue of $b_1$ modulo $d$. Then, the meander corresponding to $a_1+...+a_k=b_1+...+b_l$ is good if and only if good is the one corresponding to
$$
(d-r)+r+a_2+...+a_k=b_2+...+b_l
$$
(in case $r$ is zero it must be discarded).

Here are the first 111 of the $a(n)$
$$
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 2 \\
 3 & 6 \\
 4 & 14 \\
 5 & 34 \\
 6 & 68 \\
 7 & 150 \\
 8 & 296 \\
 9 & 586 \\
 10 & 1140 \\
 11 & 2182 \\
 12 & 4130 \\
 13 & 7678 \\
 14 & 14368 \\
 15 & 26068 \\
 16 & 48248 \\
 17 & 86572 \\
 18 & 158146 \\
 19 & 281410 \\
 20 & 509442 \\
 21 & 901014 \\
 22 & 1618544 \\
 23 & 2852464 \\
 24 & 5089580 \\
 25 & 8948694 \\
 26 & 15884762 \\
 27 & 27882762 \\
 28 & 49291952 \\
 29 & 86435358 \\
 30 & 152316976 \\
 31 & 266907560 \\
 32 & 469232204 \\
 33 & 821844316 \\
 34 & 1442300988 \\
 35 & 2525295380 \\
 36 & 4426185044 \\
 37 & 7747801190 \\
 38 & 13567867834 \\
 39 & 23745303556 \\
 40 & 41557384062 \\
 41 & 72719208250 \\
 42 & 127217086618 \\
 43 & 222583616898 \\
 44 & 389294870960 \\
 45 & 681055011606 \\
 46 & 1190969037432 \\
 47 & 2083373141104 \\
 48 & 3642902097800 \\
 49 & 6372107745996 \\
 50 & 11141529268952 \\
 51 & 19487429053968 \\
 52 & 34072922408612 \\
 53 & 59593329333396 \\
 54 & 104196373919102 \\
 55 & 182231390839818 \\
 56 & 318626594336984 \\
 57 & 557234724403516 \\
 58 & 974322146677446 \\
 59 & 1703911578212510 \\
 60 & 2979322259711846 \\
 61 & 5210178551385178 \\
 62 & 9110218849890570 \\
 63 & 15931493988982610 \\
 64 & 27857226815017550 \\
 65 & 48714664885792786 \\
 66 & 85181547848196296 \\
 67 & 148957642280387814 \\
 68 & 260466741606092886 \\
 69 & 455476513314908856 \\
 70 & 796449892337843592 \\
 71 & 1392738017582218730 \\
 72 & 2435366204142605618 \\
 73 & 4258661790160448532 \\
 74 & 7446802851854147060 \\
 75 & 13021983359977438148 \\
 76 & 22770642365898383396 \\
 77 & 39818175179779177288 \\
 78 & 69627468187243597212 \\
 79 & 121754707865610780058 \\
 80 & 212904995880239240452 \\
 81 & 372297678714099281570 \\
 82 & 651015082378846020240 \\
 83 & 1138400336916804107622 \\
 84 & 1990655971732690098044 \\
 85 & 3480966121609384598862 \\
 86 & 6086972571117750179712 \\
 87 & 10643994672706675232516 \\
 88 & 18612574887590099590878 \\
 89 & 32546894313258870888576 \\
 90 & 56913010148917999572282 \\
 91 & 99520946619696571486034 \\
 92 & 174027003616514242824506 \\
 93 & 304312275771039225380736 \\
 94 & 532134871943053489298230 \\
 95 & 930517331785546952850436 \\
 96 & 1627147003755362124099240 \\
 97 & 2845309257636125017979486 \\
 98 & 4975444158602380143431196 \\
 99 & 8700305413681034236853658 \\
 100 & 15213772506611898836430634 \\
 101 & 26603545989601689878278594 \\
 102 & 46520243198912300314978832 \\
 103 & 81347565971655249247976872 \\
 104 & 142248282928801736884996866 \\
 105 & 248742274995715373879042070 \\
 106 & 434962771573005719770576034 \\
 107 & 760597063369550445571334010 \\
 108 & 1330016842349701088401439208 \\
 109 & 2325732108141510145312701272 \\
 110 & 4066887817970878716400628884 \\
 111 & 7111557640719424745330990326
\end{array}
$$
The obvious question is what can be said about this sequence - for example, its asymptotics.

Comment: Your question does not seem to contain an actual definition of these "special" meanders, at least not one I can decode from the examples.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes you are right of course, what I said is too imprecise. Here is the formal definition. Assign to $a_1+...+a_k=b_1+...+b_l$ the following union of semicircles: upper half-plane semicircles with centers $(a_1+a_2+...+a_{i−1}+\frac{a_i+1}2,0)$ and radii  $\frac{a_i+1}2-j$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant k$ and $1\leqslant j<\frac{a_i+1}2$; and similar lower half-plane semicircles with centers $(b_1+b_2+...+b_{i−1}+\frac{b_i+1}2,0)$ and radii $\frac{b_i+1}2-j$ for $i\leqslant l$ and $j<\frac{b_i+1}2$. This is a "special" meander. It is good if what one obtains is a single interval.

Comment: This sequence is not in OEIS.  Consider adding it there:  http://oeis.org/

Comment: @IgorPak
I thought about this, but could not figure out how to give a concise description that would fit there. It would be great if somebody could come up with an equivalent shorter definition.

Comment: As suggested by @IgorPak, I've put it in OEIS, it is now [A230439](https://oeis.org/A230439) there