# Mysterious identity between numbers of odd/even meander systems

Tags: co.combinatorics

Definitions:

An *upper arch system of order $n$* is a subset of the plane consisting of $n$ non-intersecting closed semicircles in the upper half-plane whose endpoints belong to the set $\{(k,0)\mid 1\leqslant k\leqslant2n\}$.

It is well known that the number of all upper arch systems of order $n$ is $C_n=\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}$, the $n$th Catalan number.

Lower arch systems are exactly the same thing in the lower half-plane.

A (closed) *meander system of order $n$* is a union of an upper and a lower arch system of order $n$.

Let $MS_n$ be the number of all meander systems of order $n$. Thus $MS_n=C_n^2$.

Call a meander system *odd*, resp. *even*, if it has odd, resp. even number of connected components.

Illustrations:

[image: an even meander system of order 6]

[image: an odd meander system of order 8]

(The first is an even meander system of order 6, the second - an odd meander system of order 8.)

Let $OMS_n$, resp $EMS_n$ be the number of odd, resp. even meander systems of order $n$.

Numerical evidence suggests that for all $k$ one has

> $$OMS_{2k}=EMS_{2k},$$
>   $$OMS_{2k+1}=EMS_{2k+1}+MS_k.$$

Does anybody know whether this is true?

(Remark: **if** it is true, then obviously $OMS_{2k}=EMS_{2k}=\frac12C_{2k}^2$ and $OMS_{2k+1}=\frac12\left(C_{2k+1}^2+C_k^2\right)$, $EMS_{2k+1}=\frac12\left(C_{2k+1}^2-C_k^2\right)$)

**Final remark:** as kidly pointed out by Gjergji Zaimi in a comment below, this is in [Meander, Folding and Arch Statistics](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9506030v1.pdf) by Di Francesco, Golinelli and Guiller (6.16, page 51). So I have to apologize for forcing you guys to think on the question answered 20 years ago.

Still it was fun, wasn't it?

Comment: Did you try putting your numbers into oeis.org and see what it tells you?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik One of them is there, but no mention of meanders. Mind that from the equalities it is very easy to derive explicit formulas for both, it is the relationship with meanders that I am after.

Comment: Then why do you ask "whether this is true"? So the numbers are the same, as you just said. Do you rather ask for an explicit bijection?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I have no idea whether the above explicit expressions indeed count even/odd meander systems, whether via bijection or otherwise.

Comment: (I've added a remark in the end to make clearer what I am asking)

Comment: then what kind of "explicit expressions" are you talking about?

Comment: So, do you have explicit formulae for $OMS$ and $EMS$, or not?

Comment: No, I don't. That they are the ones in the last remark is a conjecture. Sorry it seems the question is still unclear...

Comment: I bet this is a relatively easy exercise with generating functions; a one Richard Stanley can do in his head :-)

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Well I am not Richard Stanley, that's why I'm asking :D

Comment: @DimaPasechnik In fact I have a motivation which I probably should mention. It relates to ["special"](http://mathoverflow.net/q/146802/41291) meanders: although they seem to be much simpler than the general ones, strangely enough the analogous relationship between even and odd ones seems to be more complicated than for general meander systems.

Comment: You can divide arch systems into two parities. Arch systems of the same parity match to give even meanders; arch systems of opposite parity match to give odd meanders. It is easy to see that when $n$ is even there are an equal number of arch systems of each parity. This answers your question in the even case. If I can put together a recursion to calculate the odd number (to give a complete answer) before someone else answers I'll write this up.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Good :D

Comment: A reference is section 6 here http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506030

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi OMG here it is to the full! Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me get the skeleton of an answer down here and then I can edit in more details if you want later.

An arch system can be represented as a set of ordered pairs; for example, in the first example the upper arch system is 
$$\{(1,12),(2,11),(3,10),(4,9),(5,6),(7,8)\}$$
 and the lower arch system is $$\{(1,8),(2,5),(3,4),(6,7),(9,10),(11,12)\}.$$ The numbers in each pair are always of opposite parity.

Define the parity of an arch system as
$$
\prod_{\text{pairs }(a,b)}(-1)^{\frac{b-a-1}{2}}
$$
so the parity of the upper arch system is $-1$ and the parity of the lower arch system is $+1$.

It is not hard to see that the parity of a meander $m$ (where odd is identified with $-1$ and even with $+1$) is equal to  the product of the parities of its constituent arch systems and $(-1)^{\text{order}(m)}.$

EDIT:

Consider a meander where the upper arch system contains two pairs of the form $(a, b)$ and $(a+1,a+2)$. Compare this to the meander where we replace these two arches with $(a,a+1)$ and $(b,a+2)$. It is evident that this swaps the parity of the meander and of the arch system. Any arch system can be reduced to $\{(1,2),\ldots,(2n-1,2n)\}$ by a finite number of these moves.

(end edit)

Next, let's count odd and even arch systems. Let $A_{-1}(n)$ and $A_{+1}(n)$ be the number of $-1$ and $+1$ parity arch systems respectively (formally set $A_{+1}(0)=1$ and $A_{-1}(0)=0$). Then by looking at whatever is paired with $1$ we get the recursions
\begin{align*}
A_{-1}(n)&=\sum_{i=0,2,\ldots} \big(A_{-1}(i)A_{+1}(n-i-1) + A_{+1}(i)A_{-1}(n-i-1)\big)\\
&+\sum_{i=1,3,\ldots}\big(A_{-1}(i)A_{-1}(n-i-1) + A_{+1}(i)A_{+1}(n-i-1)\big)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
A_{+1}(n)&=\sum_{i=1,3,\ldots} \big(A_{-1}(i)A_{+1}(n-i-1) + A_{+1}(i)A_{-1}(n-i-1)\big)\\
&+\sum_{i=0,2,\ldots}\big(A_{-1}(i)A_{-1}(n-i-1) + A_{+1}(i)A_{+1}(n-i-1)\big)
\end{align*}

Simple rearrangement of the sums shows that $A_{+1}(2k)=A_{-1}(2k)$, which implies that both are $\frac{C_{2k}}{2}$.

EDIT: inductive argument added.

The following inductive argument shows that $A_{\pm 1}(2k+1)=\frac{C_{2k+1}\pm(-1)^k C_k}{2}$.

If $n\equiv1\pmod 4$ then when $i$ is odd, then one of $\{i,n-i-1\}$ is $1\pmod 4$ and one is $3\pmod 4$.

By induction, the sum above, for $A_{-1}(n)$, say, is:
\begin{align*}
A_{-1}(n)&=
\sum_{i=0,2,\ldots} \frac{C_iC_{n-i-1}}{2}\\
&+\sum_{i=1,3,\ldots}\frac{1}{4}\left(
\left(C_i+C_{\frac{i-1}{2}}\right)\left(C_{n-i-1} - C_{\frac{n-i-2}{2}}\right)
+ \left(C_i-C_{\frac{i-1}{2}}\right)\left(C_{n-i-1} + C_{\frac{n-i-2}{2}}\right)\right)
\\
&=\sum_{i=0,1,2,\ldots} \frac{C_iC_{n-i-1}}{2}
-\sum_{i=1,3,\ldots} \frac{C_{\frac{i-1}{2}}C_{\frac{n-i-2}{2}}}{2}
\\
&=\frac{C_n}{2} -\sum_{j=0,1,2,\ldots}\frac{C_{j}C_{\frac{n-1}{2}-j-1}}{2}
=\frac{C_n}{2} - \frac{C_{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{2}.
\end{align*}
The other cases of the induction (for $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ and/or if one wants an independent induction for $A_{+1}(n)$ are similar.

(end edit)

Then using the relationship between parity of meanders and parity of arch systems the result follows by arithmetic.

I can supply more details about the recursion, the rearrangement, the inductive argument, or the final arithmetic once the $A_{\pm 1}$ have been determined, if desired.

Comment: Thanks, it certainly looks promising. And I certainly would like to see an argument for the fact that the parity of a meander system is the product of parities of its arc systems - in fact the whole question has been already reduced to that by @AlexeyUstinov few minutes ago. I am also puzzled by "Now the number of" :D

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე added.

Comment: OK I need some time to digest it, thanks!

Comment: I like it more and more! Do you think this parity is related to the parity of some permutation?

Comment: It has to be _some_ permutation...

Comment: Mmm could you also please provide that inductive argument for your last equality?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე done.

Comment: OK many thanks, I'm more and more inclined to accept this one. Let me just wait a bit... well just in case ;)

Comment: no problem, let me know if there's anything else I can do to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a solution, just additional observation. It is better to devide Catalan numbers into two parts
$$C_n=O_n+E_n,$$
where $O_n$ ($E_n$) is the number of "odd" ("even") upper arch systems of order $n$: the number with odd (even) river regions where "river region" are regions from upper half-plane which will be inside  connected components of future meander. (On the first diagram we have 4 river regions in the upper half-plane and 4 river region in the lower half-plane. On the second diagram 5 and 4) These sequences are known as http://oeis.org/A007595 and http://oeis.org/A000150.

Then $$OMS_{k}=2E_k\cdot O_k,\qquad EMS_{k}=O_k^2+E_k^2.$$

On this way it is necessary to prove that parity of meander  is a sum of parities of upper and lower arch systems.

EDT: It was done in the answer of Gabriel C. Drummond-Cole. Also from his answer follows that
$$(-1)^{\text{parity of river regions}}=\prod_{{\rm pairs}(a,b)}(-1)^{\frac{b-a+1}2}.$$

(Images added by OP - he thought it would be more instructive this way. Parity of an arch system is parity of the number of connected components of the gray subset of the corresponding half-plane. Note that one may do the coloring of one half without knowing anything about the other.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: the parity I use in my answer differs from this parity by a sign; my parities are https://oeis.org/A071688 and https://oeis.org/A071684.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Thanks, good to know

Comment: now that I see these parities, I think they're a better choice for this problem; mine end up with $(-1)^{k}$ in two places that cancel and these would probably not have that extra step.

Comment: My parity is defined in my answer. I also want to know what river regions are

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole yes and you said yours differs from this one by a sign. Do you know how exactly?

Comment: I don't know the definition of river regions so I can't comment yet on whether the parity _functions_ actually coincide, although one imagines they probably do. When I said we agreed up to sign I meant that the total counts of even and odd arch systems were the same for each $n$. (Cont'd)

Comment: I didn't pay attention to which is "odd" and which is "even" in this answer; for $n=2k$ both this parity and my parity for arch systems divide $C_{2k}$ into two equal halves so it's unimportant which is which. For $n=2k+1$ our parity counts agree half the time and are opposite half the time, according to the parity of $k$. Again, since I didn't pay attention to which is "even" and which is "odd" in this answer, I don't know which half of the time is which.

Comment: Sorry I took liberty to add these images and some text without asking you. If you don't like it tell me, I'll remove it.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Thank you very much for the images!