# A seemingly simple combinatorial object that must have an easy generating function

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, generating-functions

One more question related to my earlier ["Special" meanders](https://mathoverflow.net/q/146802/41291).

I am trying to isolate simplest problems related to it. Here is one.

For a composition (i. e. a tuple of natural numbers) $\boldsymbol a=(a_1,...,a_k)$, define the set of its *midpoints* by
$$
\operatorname{mid}(\boldsymbol a):=\{a_1+...+a_{i-1}+\frac{a_i+1}2\mid1\leqslant i\leqslant k\}.
$$
For example, $\operatorname{mid}(4,1,3)=\{\frac52,5,7\}$.

Call compositions $\boldsymbol a$ and $\boldsymbol b$ *unmatchable* if $\operatorname{mid}(\boldsymbol a)\cap\operatorname{mid}(\boldsymbol b)=\varnothing$.

I need any explicit information (formula, generating function, ...) for the numbers

$F(n):=$ number of unmatchable pairs $\langle\boldsymbol a,\boldsymbol b\rangle$ with $\sum a_i=\sum b_j=n$.

The sequence starts $0,2,6,24,78,284,960,3402,11710,41020,...$

My attempts so far have led to increasingly absurdly complicated approaches (like inverting infinite matrices with power series coefficients) and gave nothing in the end.

I believe a specialist can either give an answer immediately or relate it to some known difficult problem.

Comment: I checked https://oeis.org/ and your sequence is not in the database.

Comment: @TonyHuynh Oh I should mention this, I've looked there too, also for the sequence divided by 2 (obviously all the numbers are even). I thought about adding it but first I want to learn more about it

Comment: If you change the definition of mid to $\{a_1 + \cdots + a_i \mid 1 \le 1\le k-1\}$ then does OEIS give you anything?

Comment: @TimothyChow In that case it is very easy to show that the sequence is $3^{n-1}$. This is one of the reasons I hope that there must be a good generating function.

Comment: If you think there is a simple generating function then one thing you can try is to generate more terms and use something like Maple's guessgf (in its gfun package) or Mathematica's FindGeneratingFunction.

Comment: For what it's worth, here are some more terms: $1, 3, 12, 39, 142, 480, 1701, 5855, 20510, 71090, 247998, 861723$.  Note that the numbers have huge prime factors.  Eg. $861723 = 9\cdot 95747$

Comment: Typo in the definition of midpoint: $a_i+1$ should be $a_{i+1}$

Comment: @LiorSilberman No no it is as intended. "Geometrically" it is really the midpoint: a composition $(a_1,...,a_k)$ of $n$ is more or less the same as a partition of the set $\{1,...,n\}$ of points of the real line into disjoint subsets of contiguous points, $\{1,...,a_1\}$, $\{a_1+1,...,a_1+a_2\}$, $\{a_1+a_2+1,...,a_1+a_2+a_3\}$, ..., $\{a_1+a_2+...+a_{k-1}+1,...,n\}$. Then the midpoint of $\{1,...,a_1\}$ is $\frac{a_1+1}2$, the midpoint of $\{a_1+1,...,a_1+a_2\}$ is $a_1+\frac{a_2+1}2$, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The number of unmatchable pairs can be computed with the formula:
$$F(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} (-1)^k \sum_{0<m_1<\dots<m_k<2n} \left( \sum_{0\le s_1<\dots<s_k<n=s_{k+1}\atop s_i<m_i/2} g(s_1)\prod_{i=1}^k g(s_i+s_{i+1}-m_i)\right)^2,$$ 
where 
$$g(t) = \begin{cases} 
0, &\text{if}\ t<0;\\
1, &\text{if}\ t=0;\\
2^{t-1}, &\text{if}\ t\geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$

**UPDATE #2** (02/14/16). The expression being squared in the formula for $F(n)$ equals the coefficient of $x_1^{m_1}x_2^{m_2-m_1}\cdots x_k^{m_k-m_{k-1}}x_{k+1}^{2n-m_k}$ in
$$G(x_1^2)\cdot \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{x_i x_{i+1}}{1-x_ix_{i+1}}\cdot G(x_{i+1}^2),$$
where $G(x)$ is the generating function for $g(s)$:
$$G(x) = \sum_{s=0}^\infty g(s)\cdot x^s = \frac{1-x}{1-2x}.$$
Without squaring this would lead to almost trivial summation of these coefficients, but summation with squaring remains a challenge I do not yet know how to address. [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_identity) may be relevant here somehow.

P.S. Midpoints have also a nice geometrical interpretation in terms of certain lattice paths, <s>which I can explain later if there is interest.</s> see update below.

P.S. #2 Here is my PARI/GP code, which implements the above formula for $F(n)$:

```
{ g(t) = if(t<0, return(0)); if(t==0,1,2^(t-1)); }
{ f(n,m) = my(r=0); if(#m==0,return(g(n))); forvec(s=vector(#m,i,[0,(m[i]-1)\2]), r += prod(i=0,#m, g(if(i<#m,s[i+1],n)-if(i>0,m[i]-s[i],0));); ,2); r; }
{ F(n) = my(r=0); for(k=0,2*n-1, forvec(m=vector(k,i,[1,2*n-1]), r+=(-1)^k*f(n,m)^2; ,2); ); r; }
```

**UPDATE #1** (adjusted per suggestion of მამუკაჯიბლაძე).

I will illustrate the path interpretation on the example of $a=(1,3,2,3,4)$ with the sum $n=13$.

I define the "modified" middle points (obtained from the original ones by multiplying by 2 and subtracting 1) as
$$m_i = 2(a_1+\dots+a_{i-1})+a_i.$$
In our example, we have $m=(1,5,10,15,22)$. 
Let us represent these entities as a path:
$$(0,0) \to (m_1,-a_1) \to (m_2,a_2) \to (m_3,-a_3) \to \dots \to (2n,0).$$
It can be seen that this path consists of alternating diagonal -45° and +45° steps, each of which crosses the $x$-axis but does not visit it, except for the start and end points. In other words, the intermediate vertices in this path alternatingly lie below and above the $x$-axis and their $x$-coordinates correspond to the modified middle points of $a$. Clearly, vectors $a$ and such paths are in one-to-one correspondence.

Here is the path for our example.

[image: Path corresponding to $a=(1,3,2,3,4)$.]

Comment: Yes I am very interested to hear about the connection with lattice paths, please do explain.

Comment: Hm, how many terms can you compute with this formula?  Using your code, I only get until something like $F(10) = 2\cdot 20510=41020$, but I have no energy to tell whether the code is inefficient or the formula...

Comment: @MartinRubey: The code is just for verification purposes, I did not claim its efficiency.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I've added the geometric interpretation.

Comment: Nice. It could also be $(0,0)\to(m_1,-a_1)\to(m_2,a_2)\to(m_3,-a_3)\to...$, so that all steps are 45°, alternatingly below and above the horizontal axis. I wonder whether a similar geometric meaning can be given to unmatchability of a pair...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Unmatchable pair is a pair of paths where all vertices have distinct $x$-coordinates.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: paths with 45° are indeed nicer. I'll update the illustration.

Comment: Yes this looks nicer, and more and more familiar too. You should speak about $x$-axis throughout though.

Comment: Parseval's identity may indeed be relevant. Btw I have a closely related rational generating function with squared coefficients again rational, I would expect this quite rare: writing$$\frac{1-t^2}{1-2t^2-zt}=\sum f_n(z)t^n$$one has$$\sum f_n(z)^2t^n=\frac{(1-2t)(1-3t^2)}{(1+2t)((1-2t)^2-z^2t)}.$$

Comment: In fact, if I am not mistaken, Parseval's identity gives that if you know $F(t)=\sum f_nt^n$, then $\sum f_n^2t^n$ can be computed as the residue at $x=0$ of $F(tx)F(t/x)/x$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I'm afraid this is not so straightforward. The residue approach seems to fail even in the simple case of $f_n=1$ and $F(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$.

Comment: Hmmm well it still holds "sort of" :D - I mean, Taylor expanding $\frac1{1-tx}\frac1{1-t/x}/x$ in $t$ one gets $\sum\frac{1-x^{2n}}{(1-x^2)x^n}t^{n-1}$, and residue of $\frac{1-x^{2n}}{(1-x^2)x^n}$ is 1 for odd $n$. I think also in general case this works formally, i.e. coefficientwise.

Comment: (and in the previous comment it should be $\sum f_n^2t^{2n}$)

Comment: Could you actually add the explicit expression for the result of summation without squaring?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Without squaring, the sum over $m$'s equals the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ in $(1-x)^{-k}G(x)^{k+1}=(1-x)(1-2x)^{-k-1}$.

Comment: So it is $2^{n-k-1}\binom nk\frac{n+k}n=2^{n-k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n+k}k$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes.

Answer (score 5):

I've now got an explicit formula for the generating function; after several simplifications it is still quite messy. Still decided to show it (in a separate answer, adding this to the old one would make it too long I think), maybe somebody can use it for a better answer. The proof is equally messy and uninspiring, it consists in making the functional equation from the recursion which I described in my previous answer.

So let $f(q)=\sum F(n)q^n$. Then,
$$
f(q)=\frac AB,
$$
where
$$
A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty
(-1)^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^n
\frac{(1-2q^k)^2}{(1-q^k)(1-4q^{k+1})}
\frac{1+q-4q^{n+1}}{1-2q^n}\left(\frac{q^2}{2(1-q)}\right)^n
$$
and
$$
B=\sum_{n=0}^\infty
(-1)^n\prod_{k=1}^n
\frac{(1-2q^k)^2}{(1-q^k)(1-4q^{k+1})}
\left(\frac{1-q}{1-2q^n}+2\frac{1-2q}{(1-2q^n)^2}\right)\left(\frac{q^2}{2(1-q)}\right)^n.
$$
Or, if you prefer,
\begin{multline*}
A=1-3 q
+\frac{(1-2 q) \left(1-4 q^2+q\right) }{(1-q) \left(1-4 q^2\right)}\frac{q^2}{2 (1-q)}
-\frac{(1-2 q)^2 \left(1-2 q^2\right) \left(1-4
   q^3+q\right) }{(1-q) \left(1-4 q^2\right) \left(1-q^2\right) \left(1-4 q^3\right)}\left(\frac{q^2}{2 (1-q)}\right)^2
+\frac{(1-2 q)^2 \left(1-2
   q^2\right)^2 \left(1-2 q^3\right) \left(1-4 q^4+q\right) }{(1-q) \left(1-4 q^2\right) \left(1-q^2\right) \left(1-4
   q^3\right) \left(1-q^3\right) \left(1-4 q^4\right)}\left(\frac{q^2}{2 (1-q)}\right)^3\mp...
\end{multline*}
and
\begin{multline*}
B=1-3 q-\frac{\left(3-7 q+2 q^2\right)}{(1-q) \left(1-4 q^2\right)}\frac{q^2}{2 (1-q)}
+\frac{(1-2 q)^2 \left(3-5 q-2 q^2+2 q^3\right)
   }{(1-q) \left(1-4 q^2\right) \left(1-q^2\right) \left(1-4 q^3\right)}\left(\frac{q^2}{2 (1-q)}\right)^2
-\frac{(1-2 q)^2 \left(1-2 q^2\right)^2 \left(3-5
   q-2 q^3+2 q^4\right) }{(1-q) \left(1-4 q^2\right) \left(1-q^2\right) \left(1-4 q^3\right) \left(1-q^3\right) \left(1-4
   q^4\right)}\left(\frac{q^2}{2 (1-q)}\right)^3\pm...
\end{multline*}
(**Later**)

Let me add one more version:
$$
f(q)=\frac{(1-4 q) \, _2\phi _1\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2,\ 2 q\\4 q\end{smallmatrix};q,\frac{-q^2}{2 (1-q)}\right)+q \, _2\phi _1\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2,\ 2 q\\4 q^2\end{smallmatrix};q,\frac{-q^2}{2 (1-q)}\right)}{2 (1-2 q) \,
   _2\phi _1\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2,\ 2\\4 q^2\end{smallmatrix};q,\frac{-q^2}{2 (1-q)}\right)-(1-q) \, _2\phi _1\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2,\ 2 q\\4 q^2\end{smallmatrix};q,\frac{-q^2}{2 (1-q)}\right)}
$$
where $_2\phi _1$ is the [basic hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_hypergeometric_series)

Comment: Congratulations!  Does the parameter $z=-\frac{q^2}{2(1-q)}$ have a combinatorial meaning?

Comment: @MartinRubey Thanks! No idea. In fact I am now trying to use Heine transformation to switch to a better $z$. But maybe this one is indeed significant, will think about it too.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely very far from being an answer, but still.

Let $f(t)=\sum_nF(n)t^n$ be the ogf for the numbers in question.

As in the comment by Timothy Chow, call a pair $\langle\boldsymbol a,\boldsymbol b\rangle$ *indecomposable* if $\boldsymbol a$ and $\boldsymbol b$ do not have common partial sums, that is, $a_1+...+a_i\ne b_1+...+b_j$ except for 0 and total. Let $\bar F(n)$ be the number of indecomposable unmatchable pairs with sum $=n$. The sequence $\bar F(1)/2,\bar F(2)/2,...$ starts with $0,1,3,10,27,80,216,621,1703,4824,13350,...$

Let $\bar f(t)$ be the generating function for $\bar F(n)$.

It is clear that each pair decomposes uniquely into indecomposables, hence $f=1+\bar f+\bar f^2+\bar f^3+...=\frac1{1-\bar f}$, so it suffices to compute $\bar f$.

Next, indecomposables can be similarly uniquely "glued" from "elementary" unmatchable pairs. A pair $\langle\boldsymbol a,\boldsymbol b\rangle$ is elementary if either $\boldsymbol a$ or $\boldsymbol b$ consists of a single number.

By a gluing I mean a situation like this:
$$\langle(a_1),(b_1,...,b_{j-1},x)\rangle;\langle(x,a_2,...,a_{i-1},y),(b_j)\rangle;\langle(a_i),(y,b_{j+1},...,b_{j'-1},z)\rangle;\langle(z,a_{i+1},...,a_{i'-1},t),(b_{j'})\rangle,...$$

Now it is not difficult to count elementary unmatchable pairs with given "ends". For fixed $x$ and $y$ let $F_{xy}(n)$ be the number of unmatchable pairs of the form $\langle(x+n+y),(x,...,y)\rangle$ and let $f_{xy}(t)=\sum F_{xy}(n)t^n$ be the corresponding generating function; then
$$
f_{xy}(t)=\frac{1-3t^2+2t^3-2^{d-1}t^{d+1}+2^dt^{d+3}}{(1-t)(1-4t^2)}-\begin{cases}0,&x\ne y\\\frac t{2(1-t)},&x=y\end{cases}
$$
where $d=|x-y|$.

Uniqueness of gluing then gives
$$
\bar f(t)=\sum_{k,x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_k>0}f_{x_0x_1}(t)f_{x_1x_2}(t)\cdots f_{x_{k-1}x_k}(t)t^{x_0+x_1+x_2+...+x_k}.
$$
I had some functional equations when making a series of two variables out of this, but could not simplify it any further.

**Followup**

In response to comments by Martin Rubey - some modifications of the above. Since $f_{xy}(t)$ only depends on $|x-y|$, one may redefine them, denoting $f_{xy}(t)$ by $f_d(t)$, where $d=|x-y|$. Then grouping terms by powers of $f_d$ gives some additional information, but not much I'm afraid.
\begin{align*}
\frac12\bar f(t)=&\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}\left(f_0+2tf_1+2t^2f_2+2t^3f_3+...\right)\\
+&\frac{t^3}{1-t^3}\left(f_0^2+2t(1+t)f_0f_1+t(1+t+2t^2)f_1^2+2t^2(1+t^2)f_0f_2+...\right)\\
+&\frac{t^4}{1-t^4}\left(f_0^3+2t^2(1+t+t^2)f_0^2f_1+...\right)\\
+&...
\end{align*}

**Followup-2**

This could actually be added on the spot, don't know why I did not do it before. Still not a full answer, though.

The above considerations can also be used to obtain a recursion for $\bar F(n)$ as follows. let $\bar F_m(n)$ be the number of indecomposable unmatchable pairs $\langle(a_1,...,a_k),(b_1,...,b_l)\rangle$ with $a_k>b_l=m$ (thus $\bar F(n)=2\sum_{0<m<n}\bar F_m(n)$). Then
$$
\bar F_m(n)=\sum_{1\leqslant m'\leqslant n-m}E_{|m-m'|}(n-m-m')+\sum_{1\leqslant m'<n'\leqslant n-m}\bar F_{m'}(n')E_{|m-m'|}(n-m-n'),
$$
where $E_d(n)$ is the number, for any fixed $x$, of *elementary* unmatchable pairs of the form $\langle(x+n+x+d),(x,...,x+d)\rangle$ (this does not depend on $x$). Explicitly, $E_d(0)=1$ while for $n>0$,
$$
E_d(n)=
\begin{cases}
\frac13\left(\left(4+\frac{1+(-1)^n}2\right)2^{n-2}-2\right),&d=0,\\
\frac13\left(\left(4+\frac{1+(-1)^{d+n}}2\right)2^{n-2}-2^{d-1}\right),&0<d<n,\\
2^{n-1},&n\leqslant d.
\end{cases}
$$

This is quite computable, I just reached $\bar F(120)/2=58911664743785612350317153163016087887141938864410257$ in several minutes. On the whole, asymptotics seems to be something like
$$
\bar F(n)/2\sim (0.16532514842404...)\times(2.794251674002018...)^n.
$$
By the way, the first sum in the above recursion actually seems to simplify: for $m<n$,
$$
\sum_{1\leqslant m'\leqslant n-m}E_{|m-m'|}(n-m-m')=E_m(n-m),
$$
although I don't have a proof of it at the moment.

**Followup-3**

Let me also mention that the above recursion can be turned into a matrix equation as follows. Consider the infinite matrix $M=\left(t^if_{|i-j|}(t)\right)_{i,j\geqslant1}$ and the infinite vector $v=\left(t^d(f_d(t)-1)\right)_{d\geqslant1}$ (with $f_d(t)$ as in the first followup). Then
$$
\left(\sum_n\bar F_m(n)t^n\right)_{m\geqslant1}=(1-M)^{-1}v=(1+M+M^2+M^3+...)v.
$$

Comment: I'm confused: if $\bar f=t+3t^2+10t^3+27t^4\dots$, then $1/(1-\bar f) = 1+t+4t^2+17t^3+66t^4+\dots$ which is not the series in the question.

Comment: @MartinRubey Sorry should be more clear - the sequence starts with $n=1$, and moreover it is halved, so $\bar f=2(t^2+3t^3+10t^4+27t^5+...)$.

Comment: Edited that place

Comment: It's very nice that $\bar f$ is much better to compute!  I wonder whether one can exploit the symmetry of $f_{x,y}$ apart from the trivial observation that the summand corresponding to $x_0,\dots,x_k$ is the same as the one corresponding to $x_k,\dots, x_0$.

Comment: @MartinRubey That seems to be very much to the point, and I am thinking along these lines too. Actually $f_{x,y}$ only depends on $|x-y|$, so it makes sense to redenote $f_{x,y}$ and make it $f_d$ with $d=|x-y|$; then, the sum is that of $f_{d_1}\cdots f_{d_k}S_{d_1,...,d_k}$ over all tuples $d_1,...,d_k$, where$$S_{d_1,...,d_k}(t):=\sum_{|x_{i-1}-x_i|=d_i,\ i=1,...,k}t^{x_0+...+x_k}.$$However I don't see how to approach these $S$es

Comment: Did you try to compute $S_{d_1,\dots,d_k}$ for small $k$?  Multiplying by $(1-t^k)$ gives a polynomial, maybe one can do something with these.

Comment: @MartinRubey I've added something on that. Can't find any patterns so far