# Schoenberg's rational polygon problem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, diophantine-equations, plane-geometry, rational-points, diophantine-geometry

> "A polygon is said to be *rational* if all its sides and diagonals are rational, and I. J. Schoenberg has posed the difficult question, ‘Can any given polygon be approximated as closely as we like by a rational polygon?’"

This is a quote from

> D.D. Ang, D.E. Daykin, and T.K. Sheng. "On Schoenberg's rational polygon problem." *Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society* **9**.3-4 (1969): 337-344.
>   ([journal link](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=4881628&fileId=S1446788700007266).)

I seek to understand the current status of this question. I know (from D.E.Daykin, "Rational polygons," ([journal link](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=6708660))) that
Mordell showed that the set of all rational quadrilaterals is dense in the set of all quadrilaterals. I am only finding ~40-yr-old papers, none of which are easily accessed online.

(*Added*:)
As Aaron Meyerowitz and Gerry Myerson point out, it is unknown if there even exists
a single rational octagon.
But I am interested in the dense question.
For example, is it already known that the
set of all rational pentagons is *not* dense in the set of all pentagons?
If not for pentagons, then for hexagons? Heptagons?

---

[image: MathWorld]

   
<sup>[MathWorld image of a rational quadrilateral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalQuadrilateral.html)</sup>

---

Comment: Isn't it an open question if there can be a rational polygon with more than $8$ points? Well I suppose that is no $3$ on a circle, but certainly that would be an obstacle for an appropraitely drawn polygon.

Comment: Open even for 8, I think. 7 is the most anyone has found (I think). But Joseph knows that from earlier questions.

Comment: Thanks Aaron & Gerry. My fault for not emphasizing the dense issue over mere existence. Now edited.

Comment: It appears that this 1990 paper by A. Kemnitz, which I cannot access now (beyond the 1st two pages), might be relevant: "[Integral Drawings of the Complete Graph K6](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-46908-4_48)." It appears that Kemnitz identifies an infinite class of rational hexagons, but perhaps not a *dense* set.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz: yes, it is open, http://mathoverflow.net/a/100449/5340 gives a reference to a paper.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to your last question.  As far as I know, it is still open whether there exists a dense subset $S$ of the plane with all pairwise distances rational.  Such a set $S$ would imply a positive answer to Schoenberg's Problem.  Thus, no one has currently shown that the set of rational pentagons is *not* dense in the set of all pentagons.  Same for hexagons and heptagons.

Comment: Thank you, Tony. Remarkable that even the density question for pentagons remains open (although apparently solved by Mordell for quadrilaterals).

Comment: You're welcome, Joseph.  Note that it is not inconsistent with what I said that someone *has* proved that rational pentagons are dense (but I am unaware of such a result).  If I had to bet a dollar, I would wager that it is false for pentagons.  I think the consensus is also that the set $S$ does not exist, but these kinds of problems are notoriously difficult.