# Geometry of rings and semi-rings

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras

Basically, I wonder whether a theory similar to geometric group theory has been or could be developed for rings and semirings.

One direction would be the following. Consider $\mathbb{N}$ (with the French convention, i.e. including $0$), and let $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Consider all algorithms based on the following operations:

- adding $1$,
- multiplying two variables,
- summing two variables

and allowed to have any number of local variables (no loops or other advanced programming, just allocation of variables -for free- and the above three operations). Let $\delta(n)$ be the least number of operations needed for such an algorithm to return $n$.

> What can we say about the function $\delta$? Can it be generalized to other rings or semi-rings? ***Can it be turned into a distance?*** Does it say something about the algebra of the given ring or semi-ring?

(the emphasis was added in edit, this is the part I am most interested in).

It feels a little bit like Kolmogorov complexity (except that I chose not to allow taking differences of variables, which is questionable).

**Edit** Another direction would be to consider the minimal numbers $||n||$ of $1$s needed to write $n$ by a well-formed formula with the symbols $1$ $+$ $\times$ $($ and $)$; this happens to lead to open questions, see [this answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/103171/4961).

There could be many other ways to turn finitely generated rings or semi-rings into geometric object, I would be interested in any of them.

**Added in edit** To clarify where I'm headed to, both cases show that there are natural ways to construct functions that can play the role of the distance to $0$; but I am not aware of any distance functions (taking two arguments) of this sort. Is there any that has been considered?

Comment: Up to minor details, your algorithms are straight-line programs, and $\delta(n)$ is the arithmetic circuit complexity of $n$ (over $\mathbb N$ as a semiring).

Comment: And for more keywords, the specific kind of SLPs that you consider here are known as addition-multiplication chains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) As already mentioned in the comments by Emil Jeřábek, your questions about $\mathbb{N}$ are studied under the name of straight-line programs or addition-multiplication chains. They are closely related to major complexity questions, e.g. if you cannot compute $n!$ using only $O((\log n)^c)$ such operations for any constant $c$, then Valiant's conjecture follows ($\mathsf{VP} \neq \mathsf{VNP}$) [[Burgisser, comput. complex. 2009](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00037-009-0260-x)]. In a ring you can turn circuit size in the generators into a metric $d(f,g)$ by considering the circuit size of $f-g$.

(2) While it's not a metric, [Gelfand-Kirillov dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Kirillov_dimension) of a ring is in the same spirit as geometric group theory, but for rings. It is basically the exponent of the polynomial growth rate (if it is bounded by a polynomial) of balls in the "Cayley graph" of the ring.