# Hamiltonian paths in the prime sum graph

Tags: nt.number-theory, graph-theory, prime-numbers

The following is a generalization of [this old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/241569) .

Let $n\ge 2$, $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. For which distinct $a,b\in[n]$ is it possible to list $[n]$ in some order $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ such that $x_1=a$, $x_n=b$ and $x_i+x_{i+1}$ is prime for $1\le i\le n-1$?

Note that there is no wrap-around: $x_1+x_n$ does not need to be prime.

In the language of graph theory: Define a graph with vertex set $[n]$ and edge $vw$ whenever $v+w$ is prime. For which distinct $a,b$ is there a hamiltonian path from $a$ to $b$?

There are some easy necessary conditions:

1. If $n$ is odd, $a$ and $b$ are both odd.
2. If $n$ is even, $a$ and $b$ have opposite parity.
3. Neither of these cases holds: $n=5,\{a,b\}=\{1,3\}$ and $n=6,\{a,b\}=\{1,2\}$.

**Conjecture.** These necessary conditions are also sufficient.

Solutions for $n=7$:

```
 1 4 7 6 5 2 3
 1 2 3 4 7 6 5
 1 4 3 2 5 6 7
 3 2 1 4 7 6 5
 3 4 1 2 5 6 7
 5 2 3 4 1 6 7
```

I verified the conjecture up to $n=750$ with a very stupid program. A clever program could go much further. I also checked the case $\{a,b\}=\{1,n\}$ up to $n=33000$ and the case $\{a,b\}=\{1,2\}$ up to $n=20000$.

Comment: wrong link to old question??

Comment: @mathworker21  Indeed.  Fixed, thanks.