# Is there any non-commutative ring such that every element other than the identity is a zero divisor?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

A (unital) ring $R$ with the property that every element other than the identity $1_R$ is a (two-sided) zero divisor, seems to be commonly called a "$0$-ring" or "$\mathcal O$-ring". These rings were first studied by P.M. Cohn (though only in the commutative setting) in

- *Rings of zero divisors*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **9** (1958), 914-919.

Moreover, every right (or left) artinian $\mathcal O$-ring is, in fact, a boolean ring (and hence commutative), see

- H.G. Moore, S.J. Pierce, and A. Yaqub, *Commutativity in rings of zero divisors*, Amer. Math. Monthly **75** (1968), 392

Thence, the question is:

> Does there exist any non-commutative $\mathcal O$-ring? If so, can you provide a reference where this is discussed?

I've tried to track the citations of Cohn's paper, but couldn't find an answer to my question. (See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395683/) and [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284684/).)

Comment: By "zero divisor" you mean "both left and right zero divisor"?

Comment: Yes, let me make it clear in the OP.

Comment: Such a thing would have to not be Artinian since it has a zero Jacobson radical

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Sorry, I'm not sure to understand your comment. The OP cites a paper in the AMM where it's shown that any right artinian $\mathcal O$-ring is commutative. And yes, the Jacobson radical of any $\mathcal O$-ring is trivial. So what? I'm missing the point, I think. Clearly, you don't mean that an $\mathcal O$-ring is necessarily non-artinian. Do you mean that a non-commutative $\mathcal O$-ring is necessarily non-artinian and this can proved in a more direct way than done in the aforementioned AMM paper?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part of the OP.

Comment: Does this work? Given a finite non-commutative ring $R$, we define $R_0=R$, and $R_i=R_{i-1}[a_1,a_2,a_3 \cdots...]$  where the $a_i$ are defined to be the be elements we adjoin to make every element in $R_{i-1}$ a zero divisor. (This requires some listing of $R_i$ which may be infinite, but since it is countable this isn't too bad in terms of the required set theory). We then set $R_\infty$ to be the union of the $R_i$.

Comment: I feel like units are going to very annoying to deal with here. A unit in a ring $R$ can't become a zero divisor in any overring $R'$, so an argument like that of JoshuaZ can't work. They also mess up any attempt to work with nilpotents - if $x$ is nilpotent, then $1+x$ is automatically a unit, so no attempt like that in the (now deleted) answer of Donu Arapura can work either.

Comment: @Wojowu Yeah, good point. Units really wreck this approach.

Comment: The problem seems to reduce to does there exist a primitive unital ring where every non-identity element is a two-sided zero divisor.  First note that if every nonidentity element of $R$ is a zero divisor, then the same is true for $R/I$ for any ideal $I$.    Since $J(R)=0$ (the radical), $R$ is a subdirect product of primitive rings and hence is commutative iff each of these primitive quotients are.  I don’t see how to use Jacobson’s density theorem to get a contradiction to noncommutativity if the primitive ring is not artinian.

Comment: So can the underlying group operation be non commutative? or must that be commutative and only the ring operation gets to be non commutative?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal The additive group of the ring need be abelian (that's part of the def of a ring): It's the multiplicative monoid that need be non-commutative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Sorry for answering my own question, and the more so because this is happening for the second time in 24 hours.]

The question might be open. In fact, a positive answer would imply an equally positive answer to a question stated in the introduction of Melvin Henriksen's paper

- "Rings with a unique regular element", pp. 78-87 in B.J. Gardner (ed.), *Rings, modules and radicals* (Proc. Conf., Hobart/Aust. 1987), Pitman Res. Notes Math. Ser. **204**, Longman Sci. Tech., Harlow, 1989,

where Henriksen writes:

> We do not know if there is a ring with a unique regular ring [*sic*] that fails to be commutative.

In Henriksen's paper, a ring need not be unital; and a regular element is nothing else than a cancellative element of the multiplicative semigroup of the ring (loc. cit., Definition 2.1).

The question is marked as open by David Feldman in a [2012 post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/100432/16537) from the "Not especially famous, long-open problems which anyone can understand" [big list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100265/) (see also the comments under the same post), where Feldman writes:

> Must a non-commutative ring (with identity) contain a non-zero-divisor aside from the identity?