# Open problem in analysis with just one quantifier?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I'm looking for an open problem in analysis or number theory with just one "genuine" or "second order" quantifier.

E.g.

- "Every continuous function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the property $\theta$", where $\theta$ is expressible using only quantifiers over rationals.
- "Every set $S$ of natural numbers has the property $\theta$", where $\theta$ is expressible using only quantifiers over rationals.

No cheat examples like "For every  real number, Goldbach's conjecture holds"!  That's an arithmetical problem.

In technical terms, I'm looking for a $\Pi^1_1$ sentence that we don't know how to reduce to an arithmetical sentence.

I'd also like it to be easy to state and obviously $\Pi^1_1$, so that it can be included in a logic paper without requiring much explanation.

Comment: I don't know, but you could have a look at https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0020739970280111?journalCode=tmes20 and https://www.math.ksu.edu/~ramm/papers/547.pdf and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095743/innocent-looking-open-problems-in-real-analysis and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58638/open-conjectures-in-real-analysis-targeting-real-valued-functions-of-a-single-re and https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00020-018-2460-8 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100265/not-especially-famous-long-open-problems-which-anyone-can-understand

Comment: Problems of the form: is there a countable graph with such-and-such first-order property? Is there a countable structure with such-and-such first-order property? Negative answers would have the desired form $\Pi^1_1$.

Comment: $\forall (x,y).\zeta(x+iy)=0\implies x={1\over 2}$ is a natural thing to write, but RH turns out to have a $\Pi^1_0$ form.  So your question has subtleties.

Comment: @none I think you mean to say that RH has a $\Pi^0_1$ form, that is, a purely arithmetic form as a universal arithmetic assertion.

Comment: Oops, yes, I can't edit the comment any more though.  [This thread's answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100265/not-especially-famous-long-open-problems-which-anyone-can-understand) have some more possibilities.  Is there a theorem of Takeuti that practically everything in classical analysis can be encoded in Peano arithmetic?  That might make this question difficult.

Comment: I suspect the [four exponentials conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_exponentials_conjecture) and some other problems in transcendental number theory could qualify.

Comment: Sorry, what is meant by "genuine" quantifier? Doesn't the term "continuous function" implicitly contain quite a few quantifiers? (EDIT: Oh I see -- the condition that a given function be continuous is arithmetical, so the only analytic quantifier is over the function itself)

Comment: @TimCampion a continuous function can be presented as a continuous function on rationals.

Comment: There are (open) special cases of the invariant subspace conjecture that are of the form requested by the OP, e.g., Conjecture 8 of https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/finitary-consequences-of-the-invariant-subspace-problem/ .

Comment: @MattF. That's a fair point. Can you think of a way to phrase, say, Schanuel's conjecture in arithmetic way?

Comment: @Wojowu, I gave an arithmetic translation of Schanuel’s conjecture in my answer.

Comment: A quick suggestion: to avoid clutter, maybe the candidates which turned out to have arithmetical equivalents should be deleted?

Comment: @NoahSchweber done.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm curious as to how this works exactly. For all analytic functions $F(z) : \mathcal{J} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $F(e^z) = F(z)+1$ and $F(0) = -1$, then $F$ must have the form $\text{slog}(z)$. Where here $\text{slog}$ is Kneser's slog and $\mathcal{J}$ is the julia set of $\exp$ excluding periodic points. This is an open problem in iteration theory. I'm wondering if this is along the lines. There is only one quantifier as I understand it, but I'm not too sure.

Comment: @RichardDiagram this looks $\Pi^1_1$ to me, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: @PaulBlainLevy I agree, but I'm not the best at this sort of stuff, lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The
[Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood_conjecture) is an example that meets all my requirements.

It is easy to state and obviously $\Pi^1_1$.  Furthermore [this comment by Christian Reiher](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/problems-related-to-littlewoods-conjecture-2/#comment-4395) gives me confidence that it has no known  reduction to an arithmetical sentence. (Hopefully it even lacks a known reduction to a $\Sigma^1_1$ sentence.)

Comment: Thanks to everyone that helped, either by suggesting possible answers, or by pointing out that various $\Pi^1_1$ sentences suggested by me or others did in fact have a known reduction to an arithmetical sentence.