No starter "accessible" well known open problems
We all know very famous open problems. Usually the ones that become famous are well studied and lots of progress was achieved and conjectures, partial results, reductions and so on exist. This is one of the reasons they become famous. This kind of problems are usually hopeless to attack without lots of investment of time and dedication to learn the basics and beyond.
I am interested in the other extreme, that is, I would like relatively easy to state problems which are well known (at least in the relevant area), but no one has a clue how to start solving them, preferably no one even has a good guess what the right answer is.
Let me give you two examples from my research area:

A pro-$p$ group in which there exists a bound on the number of generators (topologically) for all closed subgroups is said to have finite rank. These are well known due to the works of Lazard, and Lubtozky and Mann, for instance, they are $p$-adic analytic. However, as far as I know known no-one has a clue whether a pro-$p$ group in which every closed subgroup is finitely generated has finite rank? In other words, if a  pro-$p$ group is not of finite rank does it contain a closed subgroup which is not finitely generated?

Zelmanov solved the Restricted Burnside Problem that is there are finitely many finite $p$-groups with $d$-generators and exponent at most $e$. This is equivalent to saying that every finitely generated pro-$p$ of finite exponent is finite. He also generalized and proved the Burnside Problem for pro-$p$ groups, that is, every finitely generated torsion pro-$p$ is finite. However, the Generalized Burnside Problem for pro-$p$ group is completely open, that is, is it true that a torsion pro-$p$ group (not necessarily f.g.) has finite exponent? (I'll just comment that Burnside kind of problems are usually very hard.)


Motivation: Well I recently retired and while I do not have the energy (or talent) to try to solve most famous open problem, it would be nice to have a list of famous problems that either by luck one might encounter a counter example or by luck one might find a very different approach.

I don't understand the distinction you are making in your first two paragraphs. Generally for all very famous open problems no one has a clue how to solve them - otherwise they would have.

To many of these famous open problems people have or had ideas how to make progress or they proved special cases or they reduced them to other problems. I am talking about problems that no-one has any clue how even to start. No-one wrote a paper about them, no-one conjectured (not guessed) what the answer. Everyone "knows" that the Riemann Hypothesis is true, we just don't know how to prove it. For the problems I have mentioned, I don't think anyone has even a belief what is the correct answer.

Many experts think the Riemann Hypothesis could be false!

Anything is possible, until there is a proof,  and I am not a number theorist, however, I never heard anyone saying they believe it is false (possibly some are not 100% sure it is true). In any case, it is exactly the opposite kind of problem than then ones I am looking for.

Seems to me that no one has any idea how to start solving the $3x+1$ problem, aka the Collatz problem. Certainly easy to state, well-known, and open.

@GerryMyerson I think I saw a lot of activity around it in the last several years (I think Tao had some work on it). I think also people solved some cases and also looked at variation on it, but this something I am far from sure of.

I think I have examples in functional analysis that might count, although I am still not sure how many papers need to be written on an open problem before it is a non-example of what you are looking for

For instance, I am not sure that anyone really has any idea about how to prove (non-)amenability of Thompson's F, but does that really count as the kind of problem you are looking for with this question?

@YemonChoi not really what I had in mind, because there are many papers and ideas  on the topic, although of course contradicting ones. So indeed no-one knows what the answer is. I am more interested in those where clearly the question is very interesting very natural, but no-one knows how to even start approaching it. I guess most of them would be, does such an object exist?

@YiftachBarnea "I believe this to be false. There is no evidence whatever for it (unless one counts that it is always nice when any function has only real roots). One should not believe things for which there is no evidence. In the spirit of the anthology I should also record my feeling that there is no imaginable reason why it should be true." — "The Riemann Hypothesis", an essay by J. E. Littlewood in the anthology The Scientist Speculates which can be borrowed from the Internet Archive.: https://archive.org/details/scientistspecula0000irvi/page/n5/mode/2up

@bof I am not a number theorist, but from my general knowledge I believe there is evidence. However, this is really not relevant to the question, so I will leave it to the experts.

@YiftachBarnea I'm not a number theorist and have no opinion on the matter. In another comment you wrote "I never heard anyone saying they believe it is false" so I thought you might be interested in the opinion of a great mathematician.

@bof the book was written 5 years before I was born and Littlewood actually died when I was 10. So no wonder I never heard him talking about his disbelief in the Riemann Hypothesis.  :-)

Are there any Tarski monsters for $p = 5$?

@StanleyYaoXiao this, in one direction, implies that the two generated Burnside group for p=5 is infinite. I believe this is studied. Also Tarski monster are well studied and people do improve the bound.

How is this question different from: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100265/not-especially-famous-long-open-problems-which-anyone-can-understand

@DavidWhite there might be some overlap. However, my main point is the no starter. So I would like problems that lots of very good people thought of and lot of people found interesting, but there was no progress whatsoever. I hardly know problems like this and I wonder, why?

There has been a lot of discussion about the P = NP problem, but has there actually been any progress?

Since I think the question has a reasonable interpretation, let me get the ball rolling with an open problem where I am not aware of any partial progress or proposals for a proof/counterexample.
OPEN PROBLEM. Let $H^\infty$ denote the Banach space of all bounded analytic functions on the open unit disc, equipped with the supremum norm. Does $H^\infty$ have Grothendieck's approximation property?
Concretely: is it the case that for each norm-compact subset $K\subset H^\infty$ and each $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a finite-rank operator $T:H^\infty\to H^\infty$ such that $\sup_{x\in K} \lVert T(x)-x\rVert \leq\varepsilon$?

is there any interesting background to the question?

How about:
OPEN PROBLEM. Let $k$ be a field. Describe the group of automorphisms of the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, where $n \geq 3$.
This is a seemingly basic problem in algebra. The automorphism groups of polynomial rings in two or fewer variables are understood. For three or more variables, I don't think there is anything close to a conjecture of what they should look like.

I wouldn't call "open problem" such a vague question. Nobody can decide whether something is a "description". Even in dimension 2 (where much more is understood), there are certainly open questions about the structure of this group.

@YCor: when $n=2$, there is a known collection of "basic" automorphisms which generate the whole group. We could hope for something similar for $n\geq 3$. I agree though that perhaps the truth is that there is no "simple description" of these automorphism groups and hence why there has been little progress on this problem in 100+ years.

I see no issue with this as a problem to pose. Many of Hilbert's problems could also have been panned for being vague.

Probably a stupid question, but why isn't it just GL(n, k)?

@Vincent: look at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cremona_transformation. The point is that there is no need for the automorphism to be linear

Right, they don't need to respect the grading on the ring. That's what I missed. Thanks!

OPEN PROBLEM. Is the classical permutation group $S_N$ a maximal quantum subgroup of the quantum permutation group $S_N^+$?
This is true for $N\leq 5$:

$N\leq 3$: in this range $S_N^+=S_N$,
$N=4$: Banica and Bichon [1], through classifying the quantum subgroups $\mathbb{G}\subseteq S_4^+$ , noted that $S_4\subseteq S_4^+$ is a maximal quantum subgroup, and conjectured that $S_N\subseteq S_N^+$ is a maximal quantum subgroup at all $N$.
$N=5$: Only recently did Banica [2] use advances in subfactor theory to show that $S_5\subseteq S_5^+$ is also a maximal quantum subgroup.

My understanding is that the $N=4$ approach is intractable for $N>4$ and the $N=5$ approach should also be intractable for $N>5$.
Relative to the age of the field, this is a long-standing problem. There are advances on a restricted version of the conjecture: there are no so-called easy quantum group counterexamples. I have published some very (very) basic properties of any counterexample. There is little or no published failed attempts as far as I know.
More detail can be added if required.
[1] T. Banica and J. Bichon, Quantum groups acting on 4 points, J. Reine Angew. Math. 626, 74–114 (2009)
[2] T. Banica, Homogeneous quantum groups and their easiness level, Kyoto J. Math. 61, 1–30 (2021)
